# Site Structure html file hierarchy

Tags: html

I ran into a site structure that I found interesting. It went something like the following:
All pages on the site were index.html, however all the pages(index.html) on the site resided in their own folder and even within some folders there were other folders where an index.html file resided. Does this type of site structure make good sense.
http://www.stpaulsschool.org.uk/ follows this type of structure.

Thanks

Comment: Many CMS products can be setup to clean/rewrite urls, oftentimes for SEO or just readability. Drupal: http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls Expression Engine: http://wil-linssen.com/entry/expressionengine-removing-indexphp/

Comment: By the way, the CMS vendor for this site is apparently http://fireflysolutions.co.uk/.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it looks like the site is rewriting URLS.

So they are changing

`something/php?id=1`

to

`normal_folder/`

The site is probably using a content management system to do this.

If you don't need a CMS, then I would stay away from this.

**EDIT**

As per the comment below...

Some Web site building systems (Wordpress, etc.) will automatically generate URLs when they create new pages.  Often, those URLs are ugly and don't work well for link sharing or for Search Engine Optimization.  So, you can rewrite the URL paths so that the URLs are prettier, like what you showed above.

If you are not using a system like that and you are not generating your URLs from a database (where that could also happen), then you should stay away from creating a site with one page in each folder.  It is difficult to maintain and not great for user navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like normal URL rewriting to me. I highly doubt those *apparent* folder structures exist in their web root.

Answer (score 0):

The site isn't using this at all. Its probably using a rewrite system which lets you decide which page to fetch for which url. the directory structure you think its using is very bad and should not be used.